# ARIA friendly popover that can be tabbed out of

Tags: html, popover, wai-aria

I want to create a popup next to some data that contains a few input fields. Let's pretend that the we have the following document structure

```
<input name="before-the-data" type="text />
<div id="the-data"><!-- presents some data --></div>
<input name="after-the-data" type="text />
```

When you tab forward from `before-the-data` the popover should open and focus should go to the first input in this popover. This popover is appended to the body kinda of like `Modal` from `material-ui` so that it lies above the rest of the content. Similarly the popover should open when you tab backwards from `after-the-data`.

The popover should behave as if it were inside `#the-data` for navigation purposes but the actual position would be at the end of `<body>` for presentation purposes.

To achieve this effect, I set `tabindex="0"` on `#the-data` and trigger opening the modal and shift focus into it. This works fine so far.

Now for the question: How do I best create the following effect?
You should be able to navigate back out of the modal. My idea was this: When focus shifts from it or the user clicks outside the modal, we close it and restore focus to the element that had focus before it opened up. This can be done with a simple `onblur` handler and a `onclick` on a backplane. To support tabbing, the resulting modal looks like this:

```
<div id="backplane" onclick="closeAndRestoreFocus()"
                    onfocusout="checkCloseAndRestoreFocus()">
    <div id="beforecanary" onfocus="shiftFocusBefore()" tabindex="0"/>
    <!-- popover content -->
    <div id="aftercanary" onfocus="shiftFocusAfter()" tabindex="0"/>
</div>
```

You can see that I added two divs that you can tab to `beforecanary` and `aftercanary`. When they get focused they shift focus to `before-the-data` and `after-the-data` respectively, to simulate as if the popover was actually inside `#the-data`.

At this point, you hopefully have understood what I am trying to create. Thus, the question: How good is this approach in general with respect to accessibility and how can I make sure I follow best practices of WAI-ARIA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we close it and restore focus to the element that had focus before it opened up

That might be considered a tab trap, [2.1.2 No Keyboard Trap](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/keyboard-operation-trapping.html).  Isn't the element that had focus before the popup the `#the-data`?  So if I <kbd>tab</kbd> from `before-the-data` to `#the-data`, the popup will open.  If I press <kbd>esc</kbd> to close the popup (you didn't mention that <kbd>esc</kbd> would close the popup but it [should](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#keyboard-interaction-7)), the focus goes back to `#the-data`, which will automatically open the popup again, won't it? (Because onfocus() ran again.)

If I just <kbd>tab</kbd> through the entire process, I think it would work.  It's just the dismissing of the popup that causes the problem.  Tabbing straight through everything would move focus from `before-the-data` to `#the-data` to the elements in the popup to `after-the-data` then to the rest of the page, right?

When tabbing backwards, from `after-the-data` to `#the-data`, is the focus moved into the **last** element in the popup?  Since I'm tabbing backwards, it needs to be on the last item so that I can continue tabbing backwards through the popup and then to `before-the-data`.

> The popover should behave as if it were inside #the-data for navigation purposes but the actual position would be at the end of <body> for presentation purposes.

If the popup is in the DOM at the end, that would not allow a natural tab order.  You can certainly put it there but then you have to manage the tab order.  It would be much simpler if the popup was truly part of `#the-data`.  Then the browser handles the tab order naturally.

You also have to be careful with automatically opening a popup but it **might** be a violation of [3.2.1 On Focus](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/consistent-behavior-receive-focus.html).  See "[Example of a Failure: A help dialog](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/consistent-behavior-receive-focus.html#consistent-behavior-receive-focus-examples-head)".  It *sort of* describes what you are doing but is a little different.  In the failure example, focus is moving to an input field, and the popup opens automatically and the focus moves from the input to the popup.  Your case is a little different because you move the focus off the input first (or `before-the-data`) and then the popup displays, which would **not** violate 3.2.1.  I just wanted to point this out in case you change your interaction model.

So in summary, your current behavior is kind of like a [skip link](https://webaim.org/techniques/skipnav/).  Skip links are often implemented as "hidden" links that only become visible when you <kbd>tab</kbd> to them and allow you to jump to a location on the page.  The fact that they become visible upon focus is how your popup works (since it too becomes visible when it receives focus).  The difference is that skip links do not dismiss if you press <kbd>esc</kbd>.  They **do** dismiss if you click outside of them.  I think that's the behavior you're trying to mimic.  If you ignore my comment earlier that <kbd>esc</kbd> should dismiss your popup, then you'll be ok.  I only had that comment because it sounded like your popup was like a modal dialog.